# Loading spring xml throws SAXParseException

Tags: java, spring

I wrote an application that uses spring and hibernate in eclipse. The application works fine when run in eclipse. I package that project into a executable jar file using maven and I run into a SAXParseException when I run the jar

Here is the exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 69; schema_reference.4:     Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the doc
t <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.lilly.moveit.awetosdd.AweToSddMover.main(Test.java:49)
```

Here is my spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
```

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.db" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>


     <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.test.db.dao</value>
            <value>com.test.db.dao.impl</value>
            <value>com.test.db.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.ProgressDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">${hibernate.current_session_context_class}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="jobDetailsDAO" class="com.test.db.dao.impl.JobDetailsDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobDetailsService" class="com.test.service.impl.JobDetailsServiceImpl">
    <property name="jobDetailsDAO" ref="jobDetailsDAO"/>
</bean>


 <bean id="fileDetailsDAO" class="com.test.db.dao.impl.FileDetailsDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="fileDetailsService" class="com.test.service.impl.FileDetailsServiceImpl">
    <property name="fileDetailsDAO" ref="fileDetailsDAO" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

The code that I am using to load the spring container is

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

The project structure looks like

```
Project
-----------src/main/java
-----------src/main/resources
-----------pom.xml
```

The file spring.xml is in src/main.resources

My pom.xml looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.lilly.moveit.awetosdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>testmove</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>testmove</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>  
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.def</groupId>
        <artifactId>customjar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
        <version>${spring.version}</version>  
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                <manifest>
                          <mainClass>com.abc.test.Test</mainClass>
                </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Seriously consider updating the namespace schema locations to their new versions.

Comment: What part of _"Failed to read schema document '`http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd`'"_ doesn't make sense?  It's readable from here, but you may have a local network problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ii did change spring-beans to latest version but I still get the same issue

Comment: @JimGarrison It seems like it is a network problem but I am able to access the internet. Do I need to make any changes in the settings of spring. I am not sure how do I detect if it is really a network problem. As it is working fine in eclipse. This occurs only when i run the jar

Comment: Enter the URL in a browser and see what happens. You should see the XSD file.

Comment: I do see the xsd in when I enter the URL in a browser

Comment: You are mixing spring versions. You have 4.0.3 and 2.0.8 jars in your classpath, that is trouble bound to happen. Remove the `spring-remoting` dependency as that is now part of `spring-context` and `spring-web`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the shade plugin. The namespace handlers and schemas defined in the different spring jars are getting overwritten. Add the following to the transformers section of the shade plugin configuration and see how it goes.

```
<transformer
    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
</transformer>
<transformer
    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
</transformer>
```

Also, consider using versionless schema definitions so that you are agnostic to version number changes - all XSD files are first validated from within the classpath and only if not found go on to the network.

Comment: The problems is with the shade plugin. However adding the above transformers section did not work. I used one-Jar plugin and what I did was to generate the jar using one-Jar so that it does include all the dependencies and put the spring.xml in the same folder as jar and was referencing this spring.xml from the jar. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
    <version>${spring.version}</version>  
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
    <version>${spring.version}</version>  
</dependency>
```

These dependencies are trouble. You are mixing Spring 4.0.3 with Spring 2.0.8 jars, never mix different versions of a framework (be it spring, hibernate, jsf etc.) as that is trouble waiting to happen.

In your case this leads to pulling in `spring-core`, `spring-beans` etc. from the 2.0.8 version of spring, which dont include the 2.5 xsd files.

Simply remove the `spring-remoting` dependency (note you can also remove `spring-web` as `spring-webmvc` depends on `spring-web`.

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
    <version>${spring.version}</version>  
</dependency>
```

Another note it is recommended to use the versionless xsd files when configuring with xml this will ensure you always have the most recent version belonging to your spring version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

Edit: Added maven update

Just noticed that you are using the shade plugin to make an executable jar. When making an executable jar certain files (`spring.handlers` and `spring.schemas` get overridden. Making just 1 schema available. You have to tell the shade plugin to merge those files instead of overriding them.

You need to configure the shade plugin you have to add something like this to your shade plugin configuration

```
<configuration>
            <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
        </configuration>
```

See also [How to create spring-based executable jar with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160534/how-to-create-spring-based-executable-jar-with-maven) and the maven-shade-plugin [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer)