# Spring: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: java, spring

```
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
```

I included the jar files in the maven pom.xml. The swing application works fine when I run it from within eclipse. However when I try to run it from a jnlp file, it throws this error. I have added the `spring-tx` jar in jnlp file. Here is my spring context file.

```
<!-- from the file 'context.xml' -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because earlier I was using a single spring2.5.jar and after upgrading to 3.x , I had multiple jars. Java webstart has some problem with resolving the namespacehandler file in different jars.

My solution: I built a single jar file ([using this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160599/432283)) for all my spring modules and included it in my project.