# Error while running executable jar of spring batch project

Tags: xml, spring, maven, xsd, spring-batch

I have created a batch project using maven and using xml file to configure my jobs.

I am creating an executable jar using maven using the below configuration

> 

```
<plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                 <archive>
                      <manifest>
                          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                         <mainClass>com.batch.App</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>single</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
```

In my pom.xml i am using the below versions of the jars

```
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <quartz.version>1.8.5</quartz.version>
</properties>
```

This is my declaration of the job.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    ">
```

In my job.xml file this is the declaration of my job

```
<job id="myJob" restartable="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
```

When i run this project from eclipse it runs fine , but when i make an executable jar out of this and run it as a jar then i get the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefiniti
onStoreException: Line 77 in XML document from class path resource [job/ccl-spri
ng-job-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
; lineNumber: 77; columnNumber: 91; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcar
d is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'job'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationCon
text.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtain
FreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at com.batch.App.run(App.java:17)
        at com.batch.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 77; columnNumber: 91; cvc-
complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be f
ound for element 'job'.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAX
ParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErro
rReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportS
chemaError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleS
tartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startEl
ement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scan
StartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next
(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unk
nown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocum
ent(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadD
ocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        ... 15 more
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160534/how-to-create-spring-based-executable-jar-with-maven

Comment: This problem is mostly related to wrong schema url or bad internet connections

Comment: I used the shade plugin to build my executable jar and it worked..!! Thanks