# No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories using maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using below maven assembly plugin to package spring boot application. I am using this plug in as i have some other issues with spring-boot-maven plugin.

```
    <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.gcc.news.publishing.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

When I run it using

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar target/gcc-news-publishing-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar.
```

I am getting below exception.

```
Exception:
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are u
sing a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
2018-07-12 22:20:56.031 ERROR 22836 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplica
tion               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to proces
s import candidates for configuration class [com.gcc.news.publishing.Application
]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration
 classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging
, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.proce
ssDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:556) ~[gcc-news-publishi
ng-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
```

when i manually edited META-INF/spring.factories file in the packaged jar and replaced the content in it with below one , it is running fine without any issues. Please help me  how can i make sure the content i manually placed  in spring.factories file to get into the same file automatically without the need for editing the jar file manually.

Content I have manually placed in spring.factories file in packaged jar:

```
     # Initializers
        org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\


org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer

    # Application Listeners
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer

    # Auto Configuration Import Listeners
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportListener=\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionEvaluationReportAutoConfigurationImportListener

    # Auto Configuration Import Filters
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter=\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition

    # Auto Configure
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cloud.CloudAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.ldap.LdapDataAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.ldap.LdapRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.solr.SolrRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.jest.JestAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.LdapAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.DeviceDelegatingViewResolverAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.SitePreferenceAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.reactor.ReactorAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sendgrid.SendGridAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.SocialWebAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.FacebookAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.LinkedInAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.TwitterAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration

    # Failure analyzers
    org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBeanCreationFailureAnalyzer,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer

    # Template availability providers
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.template.TemplateAvailabilityProvider=\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JspTemplateAvailabilityProvider
```

Note: i have tried palcing the content in /src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories but  it is not being picked up by spring boot when i packaged the jar file.

Answer (score 8):

You have to explicitly add the transformers to add the `spring.factories` content

```
<configuration>
<transformers>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
        <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
    </transformer>
</transformers>
</configuration>
```

Please refer [How to create spring-based executable jar with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160534/how-to-create-spring-based-executable-jar-with-maven)

Alternatively, you can also use a spring-boot custom layout to package your application

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/custom-layout.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!. I have replaced assembly plugin with Shade plugin and added the transformer code you mentioned. Now my spring.factories file is getting copied into META-INF folder in packaged jar file. Now I am able to run it using java -classpath target/gcc-news-publishing-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev com.gcc.news.publishing.Application . Can you guide me how to set the mainClass using shade plugin so i can get the runnable jar?

Comment: i have tried adding below: 

<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
   <mainClass>com.gcc.news.publishing.Application</mainClass>
</transformer>

But i am getting below error while packaging the applicaiton:

Failed to execute goal  Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer