# Difference between projectHelper.attachArtifact and project.getArtifact().setFile

Tags: maven, deployment, mule, munit

I'm currently facing an issue with the execution of my MUnit tests using the command line.

I'm facing a problem of "duplicate project artifact assignment" Using version 1.2 of mule-domain-maven-plugin [that was fixed here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-esb-maven-tools/commit/04d07f777715fd3e4ada24e87ec03271d5a2ac35) with version 1.3. Removing this line of code causes FileNotFoundException on mule-domain-config.xml when running my MUnit.

After decompiling the code, I can see that 1.2 (which works with my MUnits), has 2 lines of code :

```java
this.projectHelper.attachArtifact(this.project, "zip", domain);
this.project.getArtifact().setFile(domain);
```

I can see that 1.3 has only this line :

```java
this.projectHelper.attachArtifact(this.project, "zip", domain);
```

Does anybody know the difference between `this.projectHelper.attachArtifact(this.project, "zip", domain);` and    `this.project.getArtifact().setFile(domain);` and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the same as the difference between the main artifact and attached artifacts.

First of all, an artifact is, put simply, an object containing the [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) pointing to it (group id / artifact id / version / classifier / type), a repository where to resolve it or where it was resolved, and a file, which is the actual concrete file to use / download / upload.

Except for POM projects, a Maven project generates a single main artifact. It depends on its packaging; for example a project with a packaging of `jar` will create a main JAR artifact whose file contains all the classes of your project, and a project with a packaging of `war` will create the web application. Furthermore, the project itself is tied to its POM file; this means that a project, not only has a file for its main artifact, but also has reference to the POM file that created it. It is only for projects of packaging `pom` that no main artifact will be created; this is because such projects are parent or aggregator projects, containing build logic to be shared between multiple projects, but they do not produce a main deliverable.

In addition to this, a project has attached, or secondary, artifacts. They correspond to additional artifacts that are also generated during the build of a project, and differ from the main one by their [classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909634/what-is-the-purpose-of-classifier-tag-in-maven) and/or type, and, naturally, their actual file. Those additional artifacts are installed and deployed alongside the main one. As an example, a typical project of packaging `jar` would also generate its Javadoc and Sources as a JAR file as attached artifacts having the classifier `javadoc` and `sources`. It follows that a project of packaging `pom` can only have attached artifacts, since it has no main artifact. Finally, it is perfectly allowed to have a project without attached artifacts; only the main one (or none at all in case of a `pom` project) would get deployed.

Inside a Maven plugin, all those considerations comes down to the following:

- The main artifact of a project is retrieved with [`project.getArtifact()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getArtifact()), as an [`Artifact`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html).
- [`project.getArtifact().setFile(...)`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html#setFile(java.io.File)) sets the actual file of the main artifact of the project. Again, for a project of packaging `jar`, this would be the actual JAR file that was generated on-disk. Concrete example: [it is what the Maven JAR plugin does](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-jar-plugin-3.0.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/jar/AbstractJarMojo.java?view=markup#l268).
- The [`MavenProjectHelper`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.html) component is used to attach artifacts to the project. [`projectHelper.attachArtifact(project, "zip", file);`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.html#attachArtifact(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) would attach an artifact of type ZIP to the given project, with no classifier, and whose file is the given file. There is an overload to attach an artifact [with a classifier](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.html#attachArtifact(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)). Concrete example: [it is what the Maven Assembly Plugin does](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-assembly-plugin-3.0.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java?view=markup#l487) when it is configured to attach the artifacts it produces.
- [`project.setFile(file)`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#setFile(java.io.File)) sets the POM file of the Maven project that created it.

To give examples, we can consider the artifacts deployed [under `org.mule.tools.maven` in Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/tools/maven/). Under the artifact id [`mule-maven-plugin`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-maven-plugin/2.1/), there are multiple files:

- `mule-maven-plugin-2.1.jar` is the main artifact file,
- which was created by the POM file `mule-maven-plugin-2.1.pom`,
- while `mule-maven-plugin-2.1-javadoc.jar` and `mule-maven-plugin-2.1-sources.jar` are attached with their respective classifier.

As second example, consider the artifact id [`mule-esb-maven-tools`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-esb-maven-tools/1.1/). The only file deployed (except for the hash files) is `mule-esb-maven-tools-1.1.pom`. This is perfectly normal since it's a POM project, so it has no main artifact (there are no JARs or other deployed); there's only the POM file of the project, with no attached artifacts.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a million