# How to change behavior according to maven/gradle scope?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

How to make maven/gradle package change what it’s exported by scope? Is it possible?
Like, use like this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.blahblah</groupId>
  <artifactId>anything</artifactId>
  <version>5.8</version>
  <scope>test<scope/>
</dependency>
```

To get different binaries by use this another way

```
[...]
  <scope>compile<scope/>
[...]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Please give a concrete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes and no - sort of.

The general guideline is to create one artifact per pom.xml - most tools work quite nice with this concept. As soon as you go beyond sometimes funky stuff happens. Changing the jar only by scope isn't possible afaik. It would also confuse people a lot. And probably will make troubleshooting very difficult.

But there is a workaround. As you mentioned tests: the jar plugin allows you to export the classes in src/test/java as test-jar and use that as dependency specifying a type.

See [How to create a test-jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html).

I assume the same mechanism with the type can be used for other things as well.

There is also the concept of classifiers (this is usually used for sources, javadoc and things like that). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909634/what-is-the-purpose-of-mavens-dependency-declarations-classifier-property/).

While these things tend to work with maven on the command line, IDEs sometimes start to behave a bit weird if you push type and classifier usage too far.